# SSL connections in Qt 5.7

Tags: c++, macos, qt, security, ssl

Since upgrading from Qt 5.4 to 5.7, SSL connections using `QNetworkAccessManager::get` are now failing with an error code `QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError` and error message `SSLRead failed: -9842`.

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.myserver.com")));
```

Error -9842 corresponds to the Apple error [errSSLClientCertRequested](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=errSSLClientCertRequested) (server has requested a client cert). Our server does not request a Client Certificate. Using oppenssl on the terminal works without issue.

```
openssl s_client -connect <my sever>:443
```

SSL connections using `QNetworkAccessManager` works without problem in Qt 5.4. Do I need to set something up when making `QNetworkAccessManager` connections in Qt 5.7 or am I missing something else here?

Comment: What do you get if you connect to the `sslErrors` signal and dump the errors somwhere (on the console)?

Comment: Is this under OSX? If so, note that 5.4 uses OpenSSL, but 5.7 does use SecureTransport. So your manual test might prove nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your response @peppe. Yes it is on OS X. Connecting to the `sslErrors` signal doesn't yield any additional information. I'll investigate doing another manual test using SecureTransport - e.g. curl.